# Javascript function in c# CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom

I have the following script to get the count of custom user site actions on my SharePoint online site:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

$siteUrl = "https://mytenant.com"
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter user login name"
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter user login password" -AsSecureString
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $SecurePassword)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

$rootWeb = $ctx.Site
$ctx.Load($rootWeb)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$caColl = $rootWeb.get_userCustomActions()
$ctx.Load($caColl)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

Write-Host 'Total number of custom actions: '$caColl.Count
```

This is C# CSOM code in PowerShell. The function get_userCustomActions() is a function in the SP.js library. How is it possible that this script works? When I use this code in Visual Studio I can't build because get_userCustomActions() is a non existing method on the Site or web object in the SharePoint.Client.dll

What is happening here?

Comment: Can you try `$rootWeb.UserCustomActions` simple

Comment: That also works but I am trying to figure out why get_userCustomActions() works in this powershell script and not in a client console application.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. 
.NET Managed CSOM library will have the property named UserCustomActions:
[image]

While Js library will have the method named get_userCustomActions

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">

function runCode() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var site = clientContext.get_web();
    console.log(site);
    var UserCustomActions = site.get_userCustomActions();

    var newUserCustomAction = UserCustomActions.add();
    newUserCustomAction.set_location('Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu');
    newUserCustomAction.set_group('SiteActions');
    newUserCustomAction.set_sequence(1000);
    newUserCustomAction.set_title('New Menu Item');
    newUserCustomAction.set_imageUrl('/_layouts/images/myIcon.jpg');
    newUserCustomAction.set_description('Menu item added via ECMAScript');
    newUserCustomAction.set_url('/_layouts/create.aspx');
    newUserCustomAction.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert('New menu item added to Site Actions menu.\n\nTo view the new menu item, refresh the page.');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

[image]

Both of them will return user custom actions collection, same functionality but different name.

Comment: But how is it possible that the method get_userCustomActions() works in my C# code. According to your example I should use the property UserCustomActions which also works. But get_userCustomActions() also works. So am I executing javascript in my C# code?

Comment: @Danny  
c# and JavaScript is different, in C#, this is worked with UserCustomActions property which will return all custom actions collection. So in the C#, you need to use UserCustomActions rather than get_UserCustomActions, Did this answer your concern ?

Comment: I am just wondering why the JS function get_UserCustomActions works in my c# code. I would expect an error saying it does not exist. In Visual Studio I get that error message, inside the powershell script it gives no error and even produces a correct result